# Node.js slow broadcast

Tags: node.js, scalability, broadcast

I'm programming a Node.js server where clients can connect to the server through `/read?id=45` (where the client ID is 45 in this example). The server stores the connection in an object and will call `res.end(message)` on it when a message arrives for client #45. Alternatively, after 60 seconds, the connection will be closed and the idea is that the client calls `/read` again.

The connection is stored like so:

```
var openConn = {};

function handleReadReq(req, res) {
   var id = input.returnFromGet(req, 'id'); // fetches the ?id value

   // Save the connection to openConn
   openConn[id] = new Array();
   openConn[id].push(res);
   openConn[id].push( setTimeout(function() {
        openConn[id][0].end('');
        delete openConn[id];
           }
   }, 60 * 1000) ); 
}
```

If I send a message to /bcast, it will broadcast to all connections in openConn like so:

```
function doBcast(req, res) {
  var message = input.getPost('message'); // akin to input.returnFromGet

  var knownClients = 0
  var stealOpenConn = openConn; // 'steal' openConn
  openConn = {};

  for(var client in stealOpenConn) {
     clearTimeout(stealOpenConn[client][1]);
     stealOpenConn[client][0].end(message);
     ++knownClients;
  }

  res.end('' + knownClients);
}
```

This works great! However, once I connect a few thousand clients, it will start being incredibly slow. Reaching 4000 clients this way requires 16 seconds on average, which is unacceptable.

**Is there anything I could do to improve the speed?**

I've tried using an array instead of an object, which made no difference. Working on `openConn` rather than via `stealOpenConn` doesn't improve anything, either.

Comment: What exactly are you timing to get 16 seconds? The for-loop or ?

Comment: @mscdex `console.log(new Date().getTime())` before and after the loop.
In fact, it is `conn.end(message)` (not clearing the timeout) that is taking most of the time (95% or more), and the test messages were less than 20 characters.